# Kepp receiving SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO) with Laravel Breeze

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I installed Laravel and Laravel Breeze on my AWS LAMP instance. I went to the /login directory and got a login form, as expected. I filled out the login form with a non-existent user (the database that it is trying to access currently has an empty users table in.) I then pressed the submit button and got a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)` error.

I checked the database.php file to see the database connection information, and it was all correct. This is the MySQL part of it (with sensitive information redacted.)

```
` 'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', '/phpmyadmin'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '[database name]'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '[username]'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '[database password]'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
```

Any help that you could give me with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Presumably your code is somewhere trying to connect using different details. We can't see the code which ran the query which triggered the error. Presumably the error message came with a line number and file name. Can you provide a [mre] of the issue? I'd guess either a) that code uses different connection details held somewhere else in the code, or b) the copy of database.php you're looking at to see the connection details isn't the one being used by the application when you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your .env,
You should add your database configuration in .env file
Find these lines in .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

Replace them with your credentials.

Comment: This definitely helped, thank you! However, I seem to now be getting a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'phpmyadmin'` error, even though in all the configuration files I can find, the database is called something else.